# ASP.NET MVC areas with anchor tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can i call a javascript funciton on the click of an anchor tag? I am using areas as well.
I need to get the views from areas on the click of an anchor tag.

**List**

this getlist() makes an ajax call and get the view back. I dont want the page to be refreshed. hence i am making an ajax call.

Now i am confused how to invoke area.

if i am using an Action Link, I can use like this.

> <%=Html.ActionLink("List","GetList",new
>   {area="Blog"},null) %>

but i am using anchor tag, how can i do this???

Please let me know if i am confusing.

Comment: Are you using a javascript library such as jquery, prototype, ... ? Or just plain ol' javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jquery to attach a [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event handler to this anchor tag:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        // When an anchor is clicked
        // Use the clicked anchor href to send an AJAX call
        // and update a div with id="resultDiv" with the contents
        // sent by the server
        $('#resultDiv').load(this.href);
        // cancel the default action which is to redirect
        return false;
    });
});
```